# .NET Core scoped dependency injection not working with MediatR

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-core, mediatr

Consider the following code:

`Startup.cs`

```cs
public static void RegisterServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSingleton<IEventBus, RabbitMQBus>();
    services.AddTransient<IStuff, Stuff>(); // Empty/dummy interface and class
    services.AddMediatR(typeof(AnsweredQuestionCommandHandler));
}
```

`RabbitMQBus.cs`

```cs
public sealed class RabbitMQBus : IEventBus
{
    private readonly IMediator _mediator;
    private readonly Dictionary<string, List<Type>> _handlers;
    private readonly List<Type> _eventTypes;
    private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _serviceScopeFactory;

    public RabbitMQBus(IMediator mediator, IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory)
    {
        _mediator = mediator;
        _serviceScopeFactory = serviceScopeFactory;
        _handlers = new Dictionary<string, List<Type>>();
        _eventTypes = new List<Type>();
    }

    public Task SendCommand<T>(T command) where T : Command
    {
        return _mediator.Send(command);
    }
...
}
```

`AnsweredQuestionCommandHandler.cs`

```cs
public class AnsweredQuestionCommandHandler : IRequestHandler<QuestionAnsweredCommand, bool>
{
    private readonly IEventBus _bus;
    private readonly IStuff _stuff;

    public AnsweredQuestionCommandHandler(IEventBus bus, IStuff stuff)
    {
        _bus = bus;
        _stuff = stuff;
    }
...
}
```

Can someone explain why injecting a `Stuff` with Transient *or* Singleton lifetime works as expected--when `SendCommand()` is invoked, the constructor for `AnsweredQuestionCommandHandler` is called, `Stuff` is injected--but if inject it with Scoped lifetime, not only is `Stuff` never injected, but in fact the constructor for `AnsweredQuestionCommandHandler` is never even called when `SendCommand()` is invoked?

Comment: I'm afraid that your code doesn't show the problem. This might result in nobody being able to answer your question. You might consider updating your question and writing an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Steven: I'm not sure what else to include. Part of the problem is that the handler registration is happening in the MediatR code, which isn't accessible in this context. If you have any suggestions about what's missing, I'm all ears.

Comment: Reduce your code to a complete example that demonstrates the problem. Preferably create a console application, because this is something that can be ran by anyone to reproduce your issue.